# How to Restrict or Redirect user on same page?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, redirect, blazor, blazor-server-side

I am working on a C# Blazor app. I have one page named `News`. On the news page, I have one method which returns unread news. In my `App.razor`, I am checking If I have any unread news items I am redirecting the user to `News.razor`.

What I would like to do is if there is any unread news I want to restrict the user to the same page and even if the user clicks on any other page from the Nav menu or even directly copy paste the URL it should restrict the user to `https://localhost:44393/news`.

In short, the user should always be on `https://localhost:44393/news` until there are unread items. How can I do that?

`App.razor`:

```
protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
{
    var authenticationState = await AuthenticationStateProvider.GetAuthenticationStateAsync();
    var user = authenticationState.User;

    // Check if there are unread messages
    if (user.Identity is { IsAuthenticated: true } && News.HasUnreadNewsItems())
        NavigationManager.NavigateTo(RoutesHelper.Pages.NewItems.News);

    // base handling
    await base.OnInitializedAsync();
}
```

`News.razor`:

```
public static bool HasUnreadNewsItems()
{
    return _items?.Any(item => item.UnRead) ?? false;
}
```

How can I keep the user on this `News.razor` page at all times? I do not want to let him go to any other page until the user marks all news as read.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a demo page, with as much context as I can from your question,  that shows how to lock navigation based on status.

```cs
@page "/"

<PageTitle>Page Lock Navigation</PageTitle>

<h1>Page Lock Navigation</h1>

<div class="m-2 text-end">
    <button disabled="@_gettingNews" class="btn btn-primary" @onclick="AddNews">Add News</button>
</div>

@foreach (var news in this.News)
{
    <div class="m-2">
        <button class="btn @(news.Value ? "btn-success" : "btn-danger")" @onclick="() => SetRead(news.Key)">@news.Key</button>
    </div>
}

<NavigationLock OnBeforeInternalNavigation=this.OnLocationChanging ConfirmExternalNavigation=this.BlockNavigation />

@code {
    private Dictionary<string, bool> News = new Dictionary<string, bool>();

    private bool BlockNavigation => this.News.Any(item => item.Value == false);
    private bool _gettingNews;

    private void OnLocationChanging(LocationChangingContext context)
    {
        if (this.BlockNavigation)
            context.PreventNavigation();
    }

    private async Task AddNews()
    {
        _gettingNews = true;
        await Task.Delay(1100);
        News.Add($"News at {DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString()}", false);
        _gettingNews = false;
    }

    private void SetRead(string news)
    {
        this.News[news] = true;
    }

    private void NewNews(object? sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Get news
        this.InvokeAsync(StateHasChanged);
    }
}
```